# Java "this" method reference

Tags: java, functional-interface

Is it possible to have a functional interface return the class instance? Pretend I have this interface:

`Interface Foo extends Bar`

Now I need to provide a functional interface that returns Bar from a Foo.
I.e. Function<Foo,Bar>. Is there method reference for this without creating a new method. E.g. Foo::this.

This is necessary for some code I have that encapsulates and delegates to Foo, but selectively exposes some parts of the Foo interface and all of Bar.

I am trying to reuse code, but I can just create a method to do this for me.

Comment: Function.identity()

Comment: `Function<Foo,Bar> = a -> a;` which is exactly what `Function.identity()` does.

Comment: `Bar.class::cast`? But `Foo` already is a `Bar`, so you can just return `Foo` directly, e.g. through `x -> x` (which is returned by `Function.identity()`)

Comment: `a -> a` is probably the easiest and simplest solution.

Comment: I guess a bit more context would help in getting useful answers. How is your interface used by clients? Where do you consume the `Bar.this`? Why not pass the `Bar` instance directly, etc.?

Comment: It was guava, so Function.identity() didn't work. The a -> a definitely worked. I guess that was kind of obvious. My head was just stuck on using a method reference for some reason.

Comment: Depending on the context, you could use an existing method reference, e.g. `Objects::requireNonNull` (the idea of referencing `this` implied that you assume the argument to be non-`null`). Otherwise, just `x -> x` will be fine. It gets compiled to the equivalent of a method reference to a private method solely consisting of `return x;` anyway.